# Elastic Search NEST - How to Query List Field

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to refactor our old search into elastic search and I'm trying to convert this expression into elastic search query.

```
AddQuery(q => q.InvoiceItem.Any(p => p.ItemId == itemId));
```

I have a document `Invoice` that has a Field which is a list `InvoiceItems` and I need to query all `Invoices` that has a certain `InvoiceItem` in their `InvoiceItems` field.

Is it even possible in NEST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. I was able to achieve it using this syntax

```
AddQuery(m => m.Term(q => q.InvoiceItems.FirstOrDefault().ItemId,
                int.Parse(search.SearchValue)));
```

Note: `AddQuery` is just a helper function I made. Just focus on the expression for the answer.